# read localhost mail and send to locahost using Mail.app (or any other std mail client app)

Tags: apple-mail, localhost

I want to read the localhost mail on Mail.app. Currently I just type `mail` on the command line.

If I can read "localhost" mail on my Mail.app, then can I send (or move mail from other accounts, e.g. me@gmail.com) to me@localhost_name.  This way I'll have at least two accounts, 1) me@gmail.com and 2) me@localhost ... I want to use this as a way to organize very important email.

Any suggestions?